# What sense will delete or change item saved in key chain?

Tags: ios, keychain

I'm developing an application that save password in keychain in special name. But, it is ineffective in someday. I can almost rule out the code change or delete the password. There are three items are saved in same keychain group. They are no effect with each other.
**What sense will delete or change item saved in key chain?** iOS update? App Uninstall? And others?

Answer (score 0):

A keychain is an encrypted container that holds passwords for multiple applications, so the items will remain even after app uninstall.

Factory reset will definitely delete them.

But the best solution is to delete them when you do not need them.

May I know why you ruled out delete option?

Comment: The password is used to encryption. For special purposes, there no code to delete it.